# Symfony 4 - serialization of objects with ManyToMany relation

Tags: serialization, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I have two entities : Acquistion & priceHistory.
they have a Many to Many relation as below :

Aquisition.php

```
....
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\PriceHistory", inversedBy="acquisitions")
     * @MaxDepth(1)
     */
    private $services;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->services = new ArrayCollection();
        ....
    }

   /**
     * @return Collection|ServicePrice[]
     */
    public function getServices(): Collection
    {
        return $this->services;
    }

    public function addService(ServicePrice $service): self
    {
        if (!$this->services->contains($service)) {
            $this->services[] = $service;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeService(ServicePrice $service): self
    {
        if ($this->services->contains($service)) {
            $this->services->removeElement($service);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

PriceHistory.php

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Acquisition", mappedBy="services")
     */
    private $acquisitions;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->acquisitions = new ArrayCollection();
    }

   /**
     * @return Collection|Acquisition[]
     */
    public function getAcquisitions(): Collection
    {
        return $this->acquisitions;
    }

    public function addAcquisition(Acquisition $acquisition): self
    {
        if (!$this->acquisitions->contains($acquisition)) {
            $this->acquisitions[] = $acquisition;
            $acquisition->addService($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAcquisition(Acquisition $acquisition): self
    {
        if ($this->acquisitions->contains($acquisition)) {
            $this->acquisitions->removeElement($acquisition);
            $acquisition->removeService($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

It works normally, schema are properly created, entities persisted, etc.

But I want to serialize and deserialize the Acquiisition object as follow :

```
$encoders = array(new JsonEncoder());
        $objectNormalizer = new ObjectNormalizer(); 
        $objectNormalizer->setCircularReferenceHandler(function ($object) {
            return $object->getId();
        });
        $normalizers = array(new DateTimeNormalizer(), $objectNormalizer);
        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
        $tempCart = new Acquisition();
        $service_prices = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(ServicePrice::class)->findAll()[0];
        $tempCart->addService($service_prices);
        $jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($tempCart, 'json');
```

This give me the following error:

```
Type error: Return value of App\Entity\PriceHistory::getAcquisitions() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection, instance of Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection returned
```

How can I fixe this ?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Pierre

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong return type hint in your `getAcquisitions()` method, it should be `Collection` (which `ArrayCollection` implements).

Comment: BIG Sorry for misleading. The original is collection hint. I put Array Collection to try this way... So even with collection i get this error!! I edited my post

Comment: What I don't understans is that the object Acquisition $tempCart is created and it's only when I serialize it that I got the error.

Comment: It might not the way on STackoverflow, but I publish my investigation bit-by-bit.
I believe @MaxDepth(1) OR setCircularReferenceHandler() are being taken into consideration... But I don't know why.

Comment: @123pierre Try recreating proxies, maybe they weren't refreshed after changing return type hint. Other than that it's impossible to get same error IMO

Comment: Personaly I give up with complex serialization of Doctrine object. Either too complicated (for me), either not ready... :-(
Honnestly it will take much much less time to serialize it via the old school with foreach loops...

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Acquisition", mappedBy="services")
 *
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="relation_table_name")
 *
 */
private $acquisitions;
```